# JSON into object

Tags: javascript, php, json, cron

I use cron jobs to update my JSON file which contains the following structure;

```
{"country_name":"Afganistan","score":"0.00","Drinks":"Yess"},
{"country_name":"Albania","score":"3.00","Drinks":"Open"}
```

How would I then get it to automatically turn into an object like this with the data as the object header?

```
{
     "data": [    
         {"country_name":"Afganistan","score":"0.00","Drinks":"Yess"},
         {"country_name":"Albania","score":"3.00","Drinks":"Open"}
     ]
}
```

Comment: can't you update the script to write json with data key?

Comment: I think `[]` are missing in your json example

Comment: show us your code... ;) (which is generating the JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Pass your json data to [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method like this

```
$json = '[
    { "country_name": "Afganistan", "score": "0.00", "Drinks": "Yess" },
    { "country_name": "Albania", "score": "3.00", "Drinks": "Open" }
]';


$data = ['data' => json_decode($json)];

var_dump($data);
```

Output

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
      ["country_name"]=>
      string(10) "Afganistan"
      ["score"]=>
      string(4) "0.00"
      ["Drinks"]=>
      string(4) "Yess"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
      ["country_name"]=>
      string(7) "Albania"
      ["score"]=>
      string(4) "3.00"
      ["Drinks"]=>
      string(4) "Open"
    }
  }
}
```